# How to achieve same behavior as with strongify in Swift?

Tags: memory-management, swift

I have a closure with a weak self, I need to ensure that self will be retained during execution of closure, and released by closure after execution is done. Previously it was done by @strongify. Is there any other ways to do so in Swift?

Comment: Can you give a code example? I'm not sure this is needed in Swift.

Comment: @NateCook I'm not a fan of the `@weakify` and `@strongify` macros and they certainly never really reached widespread adoption. I therefore disagree with Nikita's generalization of that's how "previously it was done". The underlying `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern, though, definitely has its uses in both Objective-C and Swift. I think Swipesight's answer nicely illustrates how one would do it in Swift.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While the other answers work, another option is to use backticks. Doing so does away with having to define `strongSelf` and allows using `self` without having to unwrap optional self.

```
let c: () -> Void = {
    [weak self] in
    guard let `self` = self else { 
        throw NSError(domain: "self was destroyed", code: 1, userInfo: nil) 
    }
    self.doSomethingNonOptionalSelf()  
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\`self\`.doSomethingNonOptionalSelf()` at the end? I've seen many people use `this` to avoid the backticks. As someone who comes from Objective-C rather than Java or C++, it feels a bit foreign but I understand it.

Comment: (it took me like 7 edits to that comment to escape the backticks around `self` right)

Comment: @NicolasMiari No, this is syntactic sugar to make this operation eaiser. From Swift docs: ```To use a reserved word as an identifier, put a backtick before and after it. For example, class is not a valid identifier, but `class` is valid. The backticks are not considered part of the identifier; `x` and x have the same meaning.```

Comment: @Moonwalkr I see. The `self` after the guard is the one you unwrapped into in the guard, “shadowing” the original, captured (weak) self within the scope. It’s just that you only need to use backticks the first time, right?

Comment: Correct. It would not compile otherwise. But after that, you could use both (but why would you).

Answer (score 8):

Use a local variable to establish a strong reference to `self`.

```
let c: () -> Void = {
        [weak self] in
        // assign unwrapped optional to another variable
        guard let strongSelf: TypeOfSelf = self  else {
            return // or throw an exception, up to you
        }
        strongSelf.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but the code could be better. A weak `self` is automatically an optional, and assigning it to a (implicitly strong) local makes that local an optional, too. Since you're testing for non-nil anyway, you can be more concise with an `if let` statement.

Comment: I asked a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588431/how-to-strongify-optional-self-using-guard-in-swift-2-0) about using `guard` in this situation to shadow `self`. Would appreciate an answer there

Comment: In the update, why speficying ': TypeOfSelf' when type inference seems to do the job: 'guard let strongSelf = self  else {'

Comment: if I were I would have just deleted my original legacy approach, it's really just a far less Swifty way of Rickster's answer

Answer (score 6):

Answering on an old question to raise an idiom I haven't seen a lot of people bring up: you can use `withExtendedLifetime` to guarantee that the weakened `self` won't disappear on you.

```
let c: () -> Void = {
        [weak self] in
        withExtendedLifetime(self) {
            self!.doSomething()
        }
}
```

Note that although `withExtendedLifetime` guarantees that the argument won't be destroyed before the invocation of its closure is complete, the argument is still an Optional, so you have to unwrap it.

References:

1. [Swift Standard Library Functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime)
2. [The Weak/Strong Dance in Swift](http://kelan.io/2015/the-weak-strong-dance-in-swift/)

Comment: There is no reason for the let variable wrapper if you use withExtendedLifetime.