# How to "strongify" optional self using guard in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941406/how-to-achieve-same-behavior-as-with-strongify-in-swift) about how to `weakify`/`strongify` self, which is answered, but I'm wondering how to use "self" without rightward-drifting caused by `if let`:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.0.59 700.0.72). Type :help for assistance.
  2> import Foundation
  3> class Foo {
  4.     func guardOptSelf() -> () throws -> Void {
  5.         return { [weak self] in
  6.             guard let self = self else { throw NSError(domain: "I was destroyed!", code: 1, userInfo: nil) }
  7.             self.doSomethingNonOptionalSelf()         
  8.         }
  9.     }
  10. }
repl.swift:6:19: error: pattern matching in a condition requires the 'case' keyword
            guard let self = self else { throw NSError(domain: "I was destroyed!", code: 1, userInfo: nil) }
                  ^
                  case
repl.swift:6:23: error: binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to two 'Foo?' operands
            guard let self = self else { throw NSError(domain: "I was destroyed!", code: 1, userInfo: nil) }
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You *can* shadow `self`; you just need backticks to indicate that "you know what you're doing". For example:

```
foo.doSomethingAsyncWithBar(bar) { [weak self] result in
    guard let `self` = self else { return }
    self.receivedResult(result)
}
```

Or, in your example:

```
2> import Foundation
3> class Foo {
4.     func guardOptSelf() -> () throws -> Void {
5.         return { [weak self] in
6.             guard let `self` = self else { throw NSError(domain: "I was destroyed!", code: 1, userInfo: nil) }
7.             self.doSomethingNonOptionalSelf()         
8.         }
9.     }
10. }
```

Comment: Ah, nice! Didn't know about the backtick language feature. Seems like this is also unaffected by compiler warning settings for variable shadowing, which libraries like libextobjc have to suppress in their implementation of @weakify/strongify

Comment: Although this works, it is not reliable as Apple's Chris Lattner stated it as a `compiler bug` - and as it's a bug, it might be corrected in the future: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question completely nor your answer. **1)** The question is asking 'what should we do if a captured `self` is dismissed to early before we are done with it? **2)** To do such we have to take 1 extra step ie more than the normal `[weak self]`. We should capture it using a strong reference ie `guard let` **3)** to make things nice and smooth we use backticks so `self` becomes unwrapped, because using `weak` will convert `self` into an optional & we can can also keep the same name of *self*?

Comment: **4)** having that said. The reason I was brought to this question was that my app was crashing because I was deallocating a captured self too quick while the closures wasn't done with it and so my app crashed. The solution was using a simple `guard let _ = self else {print("self was nil and you killed/dismissed it too quick, nothing to do anymore yet no crashing :) ") return }` solved my crashing issue

Answer (score 40):

## Swift 4.2

Since Swift 4.2 you can use the following syntax:

```
{ [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    // self is not an optional anymore, it is held strongly
}
```

For more see the Swift evolution proposal [SE-0079](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md).

Sometimes other approaches than using `guard let` might be useful as well (e.g. shorter or more readable). See also the following section, just replace `strongSelf` with `self` in few examples.

## Swift 4.1 and earlier

Because `` guard let `self` = self `` is a [compiler bug as stated by Chris Lattner](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html) I would try to avoid it. In your example you can use just simple optional chaining:

```
return { [weak self] in
    self?.doSomethingNonOptionalSelf()         
}
```

Sometimes you might need to use self as a parameter. In such case you can use `flatMap` (on an optional type):

```
{ [weak self] in
    self.flatMap { $0.delegate?.tableView($0, didSelectRowAt: indexPath) }
}
```

In case you need to do something more complicated you can use `if let` construct:

```
{ [weak self] in
    if let strongSelf = self {
        // Do something more complicated using strongSelf
    }
}
```

or `guard let` construct:

```
{ [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

    // Do something more complicated using strongSelf
}
```

or you can create a private method:

```
{ [weak self] in
    self?.doSomethingMoreComplicated()
}

...

private func doSomethingMoreComplicated() {
    // Do something more complicated
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the different alternatives. We could add `guard let strongSelf = self else { return }`. It's a shame there isn't a shorter way to express this common idiom. For example something like `[if self] in self.method()` where the closure is executed if self is not nil.

Comment: Thanks @FerranMaylinch, I have edited the answer to include `guard let` as well.

Answer (score 9):

As of Swift 4.2 you no longer need to use self with backticks (compiler bug) or weird variable names like `strongSelf`. You can use `guard let self = self else { return }` to unwrap `weak self`:

```
class Example {

    var closure: (() -> Void)?

    init() {
        self.closure = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in the [Swift evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md).

Comment: A `DispatchQueue` closure is a very bad example because it does not cause a retain cycle.